# Website missing after copying to wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment-project

I am trying to deploy a website; i have copy pasted the code into the webapps\wwwroot folder by creating a folder

Then when taking inetmgr ;

i am cannot see any of the folder in the folder structure to right click and create a applciation

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound simple and I don't mean to be belittling when I ask this; but have you refreshed your IIS manager?  Are you sure you have looked in the right area in IIS or have put the folder where you thought you did?